# Can a Maxtor ATA133 HDD be fitted into a 2001 iMac?

Tags: imac, upgrade, hdd

I am a proud owner of a 2001 iMac, with a 10GB HDD. Is it possible to install in its place a Maxtor ATA/133 HDD of 40GB (produced Aug 2003)?

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at the [iMac (Early 2001) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP112) and comparing them with the information found on Wikipedia for Ultra ATA/[Parallel ATA](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) I do not see any technical limitation on why it should not work.

What you need to be aware of, however, is that in case the bus speed is lower than the ATA/133 (e.g. ATA/66 or ATA/100), the hard drive would not be as fast as it could be.  Nevertheless, I understand that it will be operational with the larger size available to you.

Comment: thank u indeed, what u say seems pretty straightforward. I should have done it myself, but am just starting on this journey...will keep u posted when -and if- I replace the hdd.